# Basic Molecule Editor for use in journals / theses?

Tags: biochemistry

My background is Geosciences and Physics and I am going to study water and biomolecules in the Autumn.  I was reading a PhD thesis about peptides and peptoids by someone in my research group and I had a really basic question abouting the drawing program that they would have used to create molecular diagrams.  I found this link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molecule_editor and it looks like a good starting place but could someone recommend a default app for creating drawings like the ones below?

[image: Text]

Thank you!

Comment: Might be better to ask on the Chemistry site.  Or the LaTeX site: I know there are some extensive LaTeX chemistry packages, though I've never used them.

Comment: With the exception of the protein, which may have been generated with Pymol or something similar, the illustration looks like an artist or designer job for a book or review.  Professionals would not be using diagrams in the style of the rest for presenting either chemistry or protein chemistry. If you search past questions on this list you will find some on protein graphics.

Comment: Thanks for the comments.  The references for the figures don't credit anyone so I assumed they had created them themselves.